# Check if a date is inside a timerange

Tags: javascript, angular, date

Having two dates, firstDate and secondDate, I want to check if a new one is situated between these two but I keep getting errors.

My approach:

```
export class AppComponent {
  first = "20171212";
  second = "20181212";

  firstDate = new Date(this.first);
  secondDate = new Date(this.second);

  check = "20180101";
  checkDate = new Date(this.check);

  if( this.checkDate > this.firstDate && this.today < this.secondDate) {
      return true;

  }
}
```

The error message says that it cannot be used the dot notation in `this.checkDate` and the others.

Any ideas why is this wrong?

Comment: Re `new Date(this.first)`, see [*Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any kind of logic or function needs to be added within a class method. Add your logic to a class method and call that method instead. For example:

```
export class AppComponent {
    first = "20171212";
    second = "20181212";

    firstDate = new Date(this.first);
    secondDate = new Date(this.second);
    check = "20180101";

    dateChecker() {
        checkDate = new Date(this.check);

        if( this.checkDate > this.firstDate && this.checkDate < this.secondDate) {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

You would then call the dateChecker() method instead.

Comment: Your question does not state how you are trying to call this logic. Include that and I will change my answer accordingly.

Comment: `new Date(this.first)` is strongly discouraged. `new Date("20170112")` produces an invalid date in Safari, Firefox and Chrome (at least).